# How to find errors in solving for RSA Algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, euclidean-algorithm

I'm working on an assignment, where we are given the values of p, q, and e.

I have *p = 11*, *q = 67*, and *e = 373*.
I've calculated *n = p * q* = 737 and *φ = (p-1) * (q-1) = 660*.

.

I found a *d* such that *e * d mod φ = 1* using Bezout's Identity, *d = 637*.
However, this *d* does not appear to work.

*M = 65*,      *C = M^e mod n = 153*

Decoding,
*C = 153*,     *M' = C^d mod n = 607*, which is not equal to 65.

.

I don't understand where I'm making a mistake, and why the coding doesn't work. Am I using the wrong equations? (Here is the calculator I used: [comptune calculator](http://comptune.com/calc.php?methos=GET&chars=0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz%21%22%23%24%25%26%27%28%29*%2B%2C-%2F%3A%3B%3C%3D%3E%3F%40ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ%5B%5C%5D%5E_%60%7B%7C%7D%7E&base1=10&S1=445083434678893245811829606151678308073771266741043275364384180573311300227522171321639335252962148219469436042252515862736175244057638846489621297196342242972670344161406303821457472682372397372968943350030451836455736968143721324077986100488513676773983417537391876315576225986719639275822279130965495053505174702497619725253759993084159624964053112958423743160106449109195077255202844811507440332800160350174764294313996213886512571236143636308058522427997010672359310351043642116469849969262342674036385417693247871325053253094109952176495057891667563794377230539464535898490841702436315979184853714811693923766539497913436549728048515054799569938045837160145118529167542048238783387508404900570897475716450176786982145469502879441189337352931722363864154254209908238558425719103832891981580952749840486947625781416823102981249723097776911187256066366755996841939048147955990644385592268689699167&base2=10&S2=737&func=bcmod&base3=10&places=900)).

Comment: This is my first time posting, so apologies if I didn't format as well as I should have.

Comment: Thanks @Moo, Wolfram seems to confirm that I did my math correctly. I'm not sure why comptune is glitching, especially since that's what the prof gave us. Anyhow, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check the calculator being used for computations.

The calculations for *d* were, in fact, correct. The problem was either with the calculator ([comptune](http://comptune.com/calc.php?methos=GET&chars=0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz%21%22%23%24%25%26%27%28%29*%2B%2C-%2F%3A%3B%3C%3D%3E%3F%40ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ%5B%5C%5D%5E_%60%7B%7C%7D%7E&base1=10&S1=637&base2=10&S2=660&func=bcmod&base3=10&places=900)) or its use. I did not have the same problem with [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=153%5E%28637%29+mod+737) calculator.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).